# Searching for a specific list of words in a text using regular expression. but it is giving an incorrect result

Tags: python, regex

```
import re  
complex_sen_count = 0  
sen = '5th grade. Very easy to read. Easily understood by an average 11-year-old student.'  
search_list = [',', 'after', 'although', 'as', 'because', 
               'before', 'even though', 'if', 'since', 'though', 
               'unless', 'until', 'when', 'whenever', 'whereas', 
               'wherever','while']  
s = sen.split('. ')  
for n in s:   
    print(n)  
    if re.compile('|'.join(search_list),re.IGNORECASE).search(n):   
        complex_sen_count+=1   
print("value: ",complex_sen_count)
```

the value should return 0 because there are no "search_list" words in the string. but still it is incrementing the variable complex_sen_count.
output is:
`5th grade`
`Very easy to read`
`Easily understood by an average 11-year-old student.`
`value:  2`

expected output: `0`
please help.

Comment: `as` is in `easy` and your search isn't "word only"

Comment: `easy` and `Easily` match, because `as` is in `search_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exactly 2 matches:

'5th grade. Very e**as**y to read. E**as**ily understood by an average 11-year-old student.'

To search for a word, add whitespace before and after the word eg: `\sas\s` (`\s` means a whitespace).